# Showing images like Google image search using JSF 1.2

Tags: jsf, panel, jsf-1.2

I want to show images like Google image search using JSF 1.2. I tried using `<h:dataTable />` inside another `<h:dataTable />` but is not working.

Comment: You can't accomplish it with basic JSF 1.2, it lacks many options that were introduced on JSF 2. Hint: you *should* train yourself in JSF 2 instead of JSF 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Richfaces DataGrid](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dataGrid.jsf?c=dataGrid&tab=usage), combined with [`<a4j:mediaOutput/>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_mediaOutput.html) to display images if you have them in local server or use html's standard `<img/>` tag if you want to link them from the Internet.

Comment: I am creating the website for training purpose, is it possible to do with normal h and f tags.